# VB.NET - WebBrowser Additional Headers - User Agent Overrides / Cancels Other Headers?

Tags: vb.net, browser, user-agent, referrer

I am trying to add 2 things into a WebBrowser control request: 1) User Agent, 2) Referring URL, (Optional 3): Accept Type.

My Code:

```
Dim Headers As String = "Accept: */*" & Chr(10) & Chr(13)
Headers = Headers & "Referer: " & "http://www.google.com/" & Chr(10) & Chr(13)
Headers = Headers & "User-Agent: " & "My Program User Agent" & Chr(10) & Chr(13)
WebBrowser1.Navigate(UrlToVisit, "_self", Nothing, Headers)
```

The above code ONLY sends the user agent. If I remove the user agent then the Accept & The referring URL are both set.

It seems that whenever I add in the user agent additional header any other custom additional headers are being cancelled out.

Is this a bug with WebBrowser / something that is not possible to do or am I doing something seriously wrong here!?!

Comment: PS. I use HTTPWebRequest most of the time, in this case I NEED to use WebBrowser so switching out wouldn't work.

Comment: EDIT: Worked out the issue moments afterwards - My Useragent which was coming from a textbox had an additional vbcrlf causing the other headers not to work, after trimming this all working ok :)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Worked out the issue moments afterwards - My Useragent which was coming from a textbox had an additional vbcrlf causing the other headers not to work, after trimming this all working ok :)

Answer (score 0):

Another note: you set chr(10) & chr(13) when it should be the other way round. CRLF as in the http standard means chr(13) & chr(10)